# recurrence relation change variable

Tags: recursion

I have a problem that I can't find the answer:

```
f(n)=(2n*f(n-1))/(n-1)+(3n*f(n-2))/(n-2)
```

can domeone help me?

Thanks for your help
Izia

Comment: what is the base case?

Answer (score 0):

I tried someting like this..

```
Let y = f(n)/n
```

From that I get the equation `ny = (2*n - y(n-1))/( n- 1 + 3ny)`

This is a quadratic in y and then finally replace y with f(n)/n.

Hope this is correct. :-)

Comment: the base case is: f(0)=1 f(1)=2

Comment: Can you send me how you got ther? because any way I try i didn't get to your calculation. thx Iziaman